# Finding index of duplicated element in arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, binary-search

I'm trying to find the index position of the duplicates in an arraylist of strings.  I'm having trouble figuring out a way to efficiently loop through the arraylist and report the index of the duplicate.  My initial thought was to use Collections.binarySearch() to look for a duplicate, but I'm not sure how I would be able to compare the elements of the arraylist to each other with binarySearch.  The only other thought I had would involve looping through the list, which is quite massive, too many times to even be feasible.  I have limited java knowledge so any help is appreciated.

Comment: `binarySearch` only works with sorted list.

Comment: Limited Java knowledge doesn't help.

Comment: Right, I know that.  The problem is I don't know how to search for a duplicate with binarysearch because my initial search value would be in the arraylist, so wouldn't it always return that index?

Comment: Do you know what the duplicate element is? Or are you searching for any duplicate in the list?

Comment: If you sort the list with `Collections.sort(yourList);` the duplicates will be right next to each other, but I guess this is not applicable to your use case, is it?

Comment: Well, what is your final purpose? If you need just to remove duplications, you can use Set instead of ArrayList. Otherwise, it's possible that other workarounds could be used.

Comment: My final purpose is to find the index where the duplicates are located.

Comment: @user1769083 See jlordo's answer :)

Answer (score 4):

Not elegant, but should work:

```
Map<String, List<Integer>> indexList = new HashMap<String, List<Integer>>();
for (int i = 0; i < yourList.size(); i++) {
    String currentString = yourList.get(i);
    List<String> indexes = indexList.get(currentString);
    if (indexes == null) {
         indexList.put(currentString, indexes = new LinkedList<Integer>());
    }
    indexes.add(i);
    if (indexes.size() > 1) {
        // found duplicate, do what you like
    }
}
// if you skip the last if in the for loop you can do this:
for (String string : indexList.keySet()) {
    if (indexList.get(string).size() > 1) {
        // String string has multiple occurences
        // List of corresponding indexes:
        List<Integer> indexes = indexList.get(string);
        // do what you want
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought of exactly this, and then I looked at your answer, and you have exactly what I thought of. :) This is good as it will only iterate once over the ArrayList and doesn't do any iterative comparisons other than the simple null check. PS: I think you meant indexList.put on line 6.

Comment: @ADTC Yes, also it finds if a String comes up more than 2 times. Thanks for the hint, updated my answer.

Comment: _"also it finds if a String comes up more than 2 times"_ that is of course what's asked :)

Comment: Yeah, when I hear duplicate I somehow always think of exactly 2. But now, after thinking about it, I can't find another word for multiple occurences ;)

Comment: Usually when one says 'duplicates' one means multiple occurrences (two or more). But yea, the ambiguity is there - that's common language for you :)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're out of luck.

You will **have** to inspect every element (i.e. iterate through the whole list).  Think about it logically - if you could avoid this, it means that there's one element that you haven't inspected.  But this element could be any value, and so *could* be a duplicate of another list element.

Binary searches are a smart way to reduce the number of elements checked when you are aware of some relationship that holds across the list - so that checking one element gives you information about the others.  For instance, for a sorted list if the middle element is greater than 5, you know that every element after it is also greater than five.

However, I don't think there's a way to make such an inference when it comes to duplicate checking.  You'd have to sort the list in terms of "number of elements that this duplicates" (which is begging the question), otherwise no tests you perform on element `x` will give you insight into whether `y` is a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Now this may not be a memory efficient solution but yes I guess this is what you were looking for.. May be this program could be further improved.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class ArrayList2_CountingDuplicates
{
public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException
{

ArrayList<String> als1=new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> als2=new ArrayList<String>();
int arr[];
int n,i,j,c=0;
String s;

BufferedReader p=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

n=Integer.parseInt(p.readLine());

arr=new int[n];

for(i=0;i<n;i++)
als1.add(p.readLine());

for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{

s=als1.get(i);
als1.remove(i);
als2.add(s);

arr[c]=1;

while(als1.contains(s))
{
j=als1.indexOf(s);
als1.remove(j);
arr[c]=arr[c]+1;
}
n=n-arr[c];
c=c+1;
i=-1;
}

    for(i=0;i<c;i++)
    System.out.println(als2.get(i)+" has frequency  "+arr[i]);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for such a method and eventually I came up with my own solution with a more functional approach to solve the problem.

```
public <T> Map<T, List<Integer>> findDuplicatesWithIndexes(List<T> elems) {
    return IntStream.range(0, elems.size())
            .boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(elems::get))
            .entrySet().stream()
            .filter(e -> e.getValue().size() > 1)
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
}
```

It returns a map consisting of duplicated elements as the keys and list of all indexes of repeating element as the value.